# The name 'txtSearchTag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, controls

I create this one in MasterPage.master

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchTag" runat="server" Width="130px"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Go!" ForeColor="#009933" Height="20px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Width="30px" />`

And this one in MasterPage.master.cs

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearchTag.Text == "")
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter a tag before search!')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        string Title = txtSearchTag.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/SearchResult.aspx?Title="+Title);
    }
}
```

And when i debug it in browser, i got this error: "The name 'txtSearchTag' does not exist in the current context". I know this is very old error but i still got it.
I used VS 2012 so the name in cs file and design file is completely matched and it's already `runat="server"`. There is nothing like *.aspx.designer.cs because it include in *.aspx file, so i cant delete cs.designer file or "Convert to Web Application". I also Clean Solution or restart project... too, but this error still happen.
It's only happen with this one and "WPCumulus" control in FlashTagCloud, the other is still fine...

Comment: Is your textbox inside the <form runat="server"> tag?

Comment: Can you show us your Masterpage declaration on the design view? starts like: `<%@ Master `

Comment: For every control I create in aspx I add a property ClientIDMode="Static" to avoid name mismatch

Comment: Jasti - that is only a good idea if you aren't using UserControls. Any complex application that uses lots of these will eventually have name collisions.

Comment: And it's only to stop .Net changing the ID of a control for the sake of client-side code.